# Trying to use the text to columns function on 2 different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use the text to column function on 2 different workbooks... works individually but when all 3 are together i run into errors listed below

```
   Sub Matt_Liam()

      Dim objRange1 As Range
       With Workbooks("orders (3).csv").Worksheets("orders (3)")
        Set objRange1 = .Range("W1:W300")
        objRange1.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Range("W1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|"
       End With

       Dim objRange As Range
        With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production")
         Set objRange = .Range("B1:B300")
         objRange.TextToColumns _
         Destination:=.Range("B1"), _
         DataType:=xlDelimited, _
         Tab:=False, _
         Semicolon:=False, _
         Comma:=False, _
         Space:=False, _
         Other:=True, _
         OtherChar:=":"
        End With


        Dim objRange2 As Range
    With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production")
        Set objRange2 = .Range("E1:E300")
        objRange2.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Range("E1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=":"
    End With

End Sub
```

> Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to convert the first file from CSV to XLSX extension then change the code to read it as the others Workbooks in the code.

Comment: how would i go about changing it ?

Comment: Hello please try File -> Save as -> Browser -> Save as type and select: "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)", open it and try to verify if the informtion is the same, If I rememeber the formulas are not working on the csv files since this are working with different schema of XML.